# How to render updated data in all open tabs in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, socket.io

I am building a demo App using Angualr,Node,express and socketio. I have a table with server side pagination and a button (model) to add records in table. The idea is when I create new record it should update the mongodb collection and emit an event and reload the fresh data in all the open tabs. This app is working fine in one tab(view) but if i see other tab the component has the fresh data but its not reflecting on the view. It looks like even though the variable in component has new value then also angular is not rendering the view in all the tabs. Can any one help me on this please?

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StockService } from './stock.service'
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {io} from 'socket.io-client';

const socket= io('http://localhost:5000',{transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']})

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stock',
  templateUrl: './stock.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stock.component.css']
})
export class StockComponent implements OnInit {

  POSTS: any;
  page = 1;
  total=1
  itemPerPage=5
  loading: boolean | undefined;
  
  public record={
    Open:0,
    Close:0
  }
  
  constructor(private stockService: StockService,private modalService: NgbModal) {
  
   }
   

  closeResult: string='';
  open(content:any) {
    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }
  
  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return  `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
saveData(modal:any){
  this.stockService.createPost(this.record) .subscribe(
    response => {
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  modal.close('Data saved')
  
}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    socket.on('stockUpdated',async()=>{
      this.fetchPosts(this.page,this.itemPerPage);
    })
    this.fetchPosts(this.page,this.itemPerPage);
  }

  fetchPosts(page:number,limit:number): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.stockService.getAllPosts(page,limit)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          this.POSTS = response.docs;
          this.total=response.totalDocs
          this.loading = false;
          console.log('POSTS: ',this.POSTS)
          console.log('total: ',this.total)
          
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }

  getPage(event:any){
    this.page = event;
    this.fetchPosts(this.page,this.itemPerPage);
  }
}
```

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


const endpoint = 'http://localhost:5000/api/stock';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class StockService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllPosts(page:number=1,limit:number=10): Observable<any> {
    console.log('params: ',page)
    return this.http.get(`${endpoint}?page=${page}&limit=${limit}`);
  }
  createPost(params:any=1): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(endpoint, params );
  }

}
```

html

```
<div class="container">
    <h3 class="text-center mt-5 mb-5">
      Stock table
    </h3>
    

    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Open</th>
          <th>Close</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let post of POSTS | paginate : { id: 'server', itemsPerPage: itemPerPage, currentPage: page, totalItems: total };
          let i = index" >
          <th scope="row">{{post.Date}}</th>
          <td>{{post.Open}}</td>
          <td>{{post.Close}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="spinner" [ngClass]="{ 'hidden': !loading }"></div>
    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="getPage($event)" id="server"></pagination-controls>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(mymodal)">Add New</button>
  </div>

   
<ng-template #mymodal let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Add new record</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Open:</label>
          <input name='open' [(ngModel)]="record.Open"  type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Close:</label>
          <input name='close' [(ngModel)]="record.Close"  type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
        </div>
      </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Cancel click')">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="saveData(modal)">Save</button>
  </div>
  
</ng-template>
```